# How to execute Arithmetic Exception catch block in Java?

Tags: java, exception, calculator, arithmeticexception

This is the code snippet:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int i1,i2;

        try{
            if(e.getSource()==b1){
            .
            .
            .

            else if(e.getSource()==b4){
                double i1,i2;
                i1=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                i2=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                i1=i1/i2;
                l7.setText(i1+"");
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==b5){
                i1=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                i2=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                i1=i1%i2;
                l7.setText(i1+"");
            }
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ex2){
            l7.setText("Debugging?");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Divide by zero exception!!");
            //*WHY THIS SECTION IS NEVER BEING EXECUTED AFTER PERFORMING A DIVIDE BY ZERO i.e. ARITHMETIC EXCEPTION!*
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Values First!!");
        }
    }
```

The JRE is never executing the Arithmetic Exception catch statement, why?

Yes, it is handing it but it not producing the output that I expect it to produce!
It is automatically displaying, "Infinity" & "NaN" on my Java application!
Thanks!

Comment: Please, take a look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, I understand but for verification! One can copy the whole code and check it by themselves! You can help too . ..

Comment: Okay, I shortened the code, and will keep that in mind! Please remove your downvote

Comment: I did not downvote you. Nevertheless, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Double and float have their own inbuilt values for infinity. There might be some other issues in your code that I'm not aware about.

Check these edits:

```
else if(e.getSource()==b4){
            double i1,i2;
            i1= Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            i2= Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            if(i1!=0 && i2 == 0){
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            }
            else if(i2 == 0 && i1 == 0) {
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            }
            i1= i1/i2;
            l7.setText(i1+"");
        }
```

This `throw new ArithmeticException();` will force your code to execute the section that you are willing to execute!

Also, check this link:                                                                                                      https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can we use this, `if(i1!=0 && i2 == 0)` instead of `if(i2 == 0)` from your code?

Comment: Yes, you can . . .

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines of code:

```
        } else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
            double i1, i2; // Comment this line to make it work like you need
            i1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            i2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            i1 = i1 / i2;
            l7.setText(i1 + "");
        }
```

You have redeclared i1 and i2 to be double. The Double type defines inbuilt values for [Infinity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) and [NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN). That's the reason your code is not executing your ArithmeticException catch block.

Simply comment the `double i1, i2;` line to make it work like you need.

> **Update**

If you want to show an error message, simply put a check:

```
        } else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
            double i1, i2;
            i1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            i2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            if(i2==0){
                throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot divide by zero");
            }
            i1 = i1 / i2;
            l7.setText(i1 + "");
        }
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: So what Can I do to fix it? Float is also giving same output!

Comment: Simply comment the `double i1, i2;` line to make it work like you need.

Comment: And if I remove try catch, then it wont handle it

Comment: But I want the calculator to give me decimals output too

Comment: Why don't you validate the input whether `i2 ==0` ?

Comment: Then what is the role of Arithmetic Exception class? If I start validating all the error conditions by myself!

Comment: Yes, but I want the control flow to enter that catch section and execute those codes too! Also, why it is not executing the catch statement by itself?